# Is there a way to find a specific glyph in Nerd Fonts?

Tags: fonts

It takes a long time to find a specific glyph in Nerd Fonts. For example, I am trying to find the Python language logo and I have no idea where it is. There are so many glyphs that it is taking me a stupid amount of time to find it.

Is there a way to find it quickly? Some sort of lookup database or something like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Nerd Fonts website has a search function.

https://www.nerdfonts.com/cheat-sheet

Probably not perfect, but your Python example comes up with 5 options just by searching the keyword "python".